# Turn exif_imagetype into caseinsensitive?

Tags: php, case-insensitive

How can i make this exif_imagetype() function into caseinsensitive? so that it will allow both .jpg and .JPG ? cant figure this one out.. ive tried with stripos(); with no luck.. Here's my code:

```
   $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF,IMAGETYPE_JPEG,IMAGETYPE_PNG);
   if (in_array(exif_imagetype($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]), $allowed_types)){

        // SUCCSESFUL
```

**GET ERROR WITH STRTOLOWER()**

```
  $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF,IMAGETYPE_JPEG,IMAGETYPE_PNG);
  if (strtolower(in_array(exif_imagetype($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]), $allowed_types))){
```

**IT SAYS: "Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in"**

**EDIT: i only get this error when i try to upload uppercase .JPG pictures.. Most modern camera uses this format, which is pretty annoying if you ask me :D many sites are losing users because of this, we must find a way to solve this problem.**

Answer (score 2):

Just do strtolower() on all input you accept before you enter them into your "tmp name" variable.  You should be sanitizing the input somewhere along the way, so just do this, too.

Comment: @ Zombie, it shows the same above error ^^ no matter where i put the strotolower() or stripos() .. Other than that my code works fine, i only get this error when my uploaded-file has the extension .JPG .. wierd?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$allowed_types = array(strtolower(IMAGETYPE_GIF),strtolower(IMAGETYPE_JPEG),strtolower(IMAGETYPE_PNG));
if (in_array(strtolower(exif_imagetype($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"])), $allowed_types)){
```

Comment: @ Poostchi, this dosent solve the problem. I get the above error ^^ no matter where i put the strtolower() or stripos() .. Even without it. Only when i try to upload uppercase .JPG files, which most cameras uses today :P

Comment: you should use lower case for allowed types, too. try edited answer.

Comment: copy that! just to make sure i understand you correctly.. Should i remove my "if (in_array(" and only write "strtolower(exif_imagetype($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]);" or what are you saying?

Comment: Still no luck :( thank you for your help though. Got a little luck with your code by replacing strtolower() with stripos() in the array string. This added the IMG url to the database, but didnt upload the picture. Still get the "Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in" .. Some how, when uploading uppercase .JPG files, this function exif_imagetype() cant regconize the image, or atleast it returns a empty string.. Wierd!

Comment: Please check this to see what's happen there: `print_r($_FILES["uploaded_file"]);`

Comment: Got this back: Array ( [name] => DSCN0001.JPG [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )

Seems like the file name is NOT empty! this is mind-boggling hehe

Comment: oh.. you need to check upload script step by step and see what happens to tmp_name